# Add code/jars to a google app engine application after initial deployment

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deployment, jar

I am playing around with google app engine and I'm thinking about starting an open source project that does something similar to Zikula (formerly known as postnuke) or more or less portal servers. So I'd like to have a kernel that provides certain services like page management, user management, ... and "modules" (or portlets in case of thinking of it as a portal implementation).

The problem I'm anticipating now is how someone could install my code along with the "modules" he likes.

Using collaborating independent apps might not work well, we the user would be limited to 9 other modules.

It would be neat to be able to add for example jars or something like that along the way.

Is this possible, or do I have to provide a tool that constructs a single file that is installed on the app engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize what I have found:

It looks like it's not possible to add jars later. Maybe there is a chance by providing a script interface (or utilizing scripting languages like Groovy/JRuby).

Any other hints/experiences are greatly appreciated!